# Initial password setting

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I'm currently using 2.3.6 of Neo4j, planning to upgrade to 3.0

background: when an instance of the server is first run, the id/password is set to neo4j/neo4j and the interface requires the first user to attempt a login to change the password.  the present version provides a REST endpoint for checking whether a password needs changing and a mechanism for making the change.  unfortunately the community driver in node.js (github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j) did not support these endpoints and I had to code them by hand

my question: does 3.0 support the same endpoints, and (perhaps more importantly) do the new driver support the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST endpoints still exist: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/authentication/#http-api-security-user-status-and-password-changing

It is not supported in the drivers.

Why do you not update to 3.**1**?

Comment: oh.  I didn't realize 3.1 was out.  of course, I'll upgrade to the latest version available.  any gotchas I should be aware of?